# Realm row inserted but no data inside

Tags: android, realm

I tried to work with Realm. Init Realm is ok but when i create object and insert (or update) to database, it may not work. I checked with some commands and saw that nothing updated, only row inserted.

This is what I did:

Application.class onCreate();

```
Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("MoneySaver.realm")
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
```

In MainActivity.class onCreate();

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Then when i started trying to add new object

```
realm.beginTransaction();
                int nextID = (int) (realm.where(Transaction.class).max("id").intValue() + 1);
                Transaction transR = realm.createObject(Transaction.class, nextID);
                transR.setMoney(100000);
                transR.setNote("test realm object");

                realm.commitTransaction();
```

And this is the header of Transaction object

```
public class Transaction extends RealmObject{
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private int category_id;
private int wallet_id;
private String note;
private double money;
private String created_at;
```

I tried to debug this. Before and after commitTransaction() called, all value are still not set

[image]

Then i use Chrome to check database. Nothing here. Even in `realm.where(Transaction.class).findAll()`  i saw 6 rows.
[image]

Comment: If `realm.where(Transaction.class).findAll()` returns 6 rows, then there **is** data in your Realm. Are you using [stetho-realm 2.0.0](https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/) ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

This is how realm works 
You should add list of transactions to realm

```
 Transaction transR = new Transaction();

                transR.setMoney(100000);
                transR.setNote("test realm object");


  List<Transaction> transaction = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
               transaction.add(transR);

                  Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm.beginTransaction();

                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(transaction);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                        realm.close();
```

Check and let me know

Comment: I think nothing differerent here. Instead of inserting a record, you insert (or update) multiple records.

Comment: I inserted it in MainActivity.onCreated() after getDefaultInstance();

Answer (score 0):

I think you just never actually installed [Stetho-Realm](https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Realm.init(this);

        Stetho.initialize(
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                        .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build()) // <-- add this
                        .build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(relamMediaModel)** will do the job

Try

```
realm.beginTransaction();
    Transaction transR = new Transaction();
            transR.setMoney(100000);
            transR.setNote("test realm object");
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(transR );
    realm.commitTransaction();
    realm.close();
```